# SQL Server: view is slow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server view to show an overview of account statements, first we calculate the latest closing balances of the user accounts to know what the latest balance was from their account. This is the **LATEST_CB_DATES** part.

Than we calculate the next business days, meaning the 2 next days where we are expecting to receive a balance in the database. This happens in **NEXT_B_DAYS**

Finally we calculate if the account is expecting a closing balance, received one or received one too late. Note that we use a window reception ending for this.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'VIEW_AS_AS_ACCT_STAT')
    DROP VIEW VIEW_AS_AS_ACCT_STAT
GO

CREATE VIEW VIEW_AS_AS_ACCT_STAT AS
WITH LATEST_CB_DATES AS (
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT  row_number() over (partition by SD_ACCT.ID order by (AS_ACCT_STAT.CBAL_BAL_DATE) DESC) RN,SD_ACCT.ID, SD_ACCT.ACCT_NBR, AS_ACCT_STAT.CBAL_BAL_DATE AS BAL_DATE, SD_ACCT.CODE, SD_ACCT.CCY, SD_ACCT_GRP.ID AS GRP_ID, SD_ACCT_GRP.CODE AS ACCT_GRP_CODE, SD_ACCT.DATA_OWNER_ID, AS_ACCT_STAT.STATIC_DATA_BNK AS BANK_CODE, AS_ACCT_STAT.STATIC_DATA_HLD AS HOLDER_CODE
   FROM SD_ACCT
   LEFT JOIN AS_ACCT on SD_ACCT.ID = AS_ACCT.STATIC_DATA_ACCT_ID
   LEFT JOIN AS_ACCT_STAT on AS_ACCT.ID = AS_ACCT_STAT.ACCT_ID
   JOIN SD_ACCT_GRP_MEMBER ON SD_ACCT.ID = SD_ACCT_GRP_MEMBER.ACCT_ID
   JOIN SD_ACCT_GRP on SD_ACCT_GRP_MEMBER.GRP_ID = SD_ACCT_GRP.ID
   JOIN SD_ACCT_GRP_ROLE on SD_ACCT_GRP_ROLE.ID = SD_ACCT_GRP.ROLE_ID
   WHERE SD_ACCT_GRP_ROLE.CODE = 'AccountStatementsToReceive' AND (AS_ACCT_STAT.VALID = 1 OR AS_ACCT_STAT.VALID IS NULL)
   ) LST_STMT
WHERE RN = 1
),
NEXT_B_DAYS AS (
   SELECT VIEW_BUSINESS_DATES.CAL_ID, VIEW_BUSINESS_DATES.BUSINESS_DATE,
      LEAD(VIEW_BUSINESS_DATES.BUSINESS_DATE, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY VIEW_BUSINESS_DATES.CAL_CODE ORDER BY VIEW_BUSINESS_DATES.BUSINESS_DATE) AS NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE,
      LEAD(VIEW_BUSINESS_DATES.BUSINESS_DATE, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY VIEW_BUSINESS_DATES.CAL_CODE ORDER BY VIEW_BUSINESS_DATES.BUSINESS_DATE) AS SECOND_BUSINESS_DATE
   FROM VIEW_BUSINESS_DATES
)
SELECT LATEST_CB_DATES.ID AS ACCT_ID,
  LATEST_CB_DATES.CODE AS ACCT_CODE,
  LATEST_CB_DATES.ACCT_NBR,
  LATEST_CB_DATES.CCY AS ACCT_CCY,
  LATEST_CB_DATES.BAL_DATE AS LATEST_CLOSING_BAL_DATE,
  LATEST_CB_DATES.DATA_OWNER_ID,
  LATEST_CB_DATES.BANK_CODE,
  LATEST_CB_DATES.HOLDER_CODE,
  LATEST_CB_DATES.ACCT_GRP_CODE,
  CASE
    WHEN LATEST_CB_DATES.BAL_DATE IS NULL THEN 'Expecting'
    WHEN NEXT_B_DAYS.NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE IS NULL OR NEXT_B_DAYS.SECOND_BUSINESS_DATE IS NULL THEN 'Late'
    WHEN AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_END IS NOT NULL AND GETDATE() >= TODATETIMEOFFSET(CAST(NEXT_B_DAYS.SECOND_BUSINESS_DATE AS DATETIME) + CAST(CAST(AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_END  AS TIME)  AS DATETIME), SEC_TIMEZONE.UTC_TIME_TOTAL_OFFSET) THEN 'Late'
    WHEN AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_END IS NULL     AND GETDATE() >= TODATETIMEOFFSET(CAST(NEXT_B_DAYS.SECOND_BUSINESS_DATE AS DATETIME) + CAST(CAST(AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_START AS TIME) AS DATETIME), SEC_TIMEZONE.UTC_TIME_TOTAL_OFFSET) AND CAST(AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_END AS TIME) >= CAST(AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_START AS TIME) THEN 'Expecting'
    WHEN AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_END IS NULL     AND GETDATE() >= TODATETIMEOFFSET(CAST(NEXT_B_DAYS.NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE   AS DATETIME) + CAST(CAST(AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_START AS TIME) AS DATETIME), SEC_TIMEZONE.UTC_TIME_TOTAL_OFFSET) AND CAST(AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_END AS TIME) <  CAST(AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_START AS TIME) THEN 'Expecting' -- overnight
    WHEN AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_END IS NULL     AND CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE) > NEXT_B_DAYS.SECOND_BUSINESS_DATE THEN 'Expecting'
    ELSE 'Received'
  END AS STAT,
  CASE
    WHEN LATEST_CB_DATES.BAL_DATE IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN NEXT_B_DAYS.NEXT_BUSINESS_DATE IS NULL OR NEXT_B_DAYS.SECOND_BUSINESS_DATE IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_END IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(NEXT_B_DAYS.SECOND_BUSINESS_DATE AS DATETIME) + CAST(CAST(AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.RECEPTION_WINDOW_END AS TIME) AS DATETIME)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS DEADLINE,
  SEC_TIMEZONE.UTC_TIME_TOTAL_OFFSET AS TIME_ZONE
FROM AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF
JOIN LATEST_CB_DATES ON AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.ACCT_GRP_ID = LATEST_CB_DATES.GRP_ID
JOIN SEC_TIMEZONE ON SEC_TIMEZONE.ID = AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.TIME_ZONE_ID
LEFT JOIN NEXT_B_DAYS ON AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.CALENDAR_ID = NEXT_B_DAYS.CAL_ID AND LATEST_CB_DATES.BAL_DATE = NEXT_B_DAYS.BUSINESS_DATE
GO

SELECT * FROM VIEW_AS_AS_ACCT_STAT
```

What is the issue? Nothing, this works fine, but it's slow. We created a graphical report to display the data for our customers, but it takes 1minute, 30 seconds to load this SQL when you have 5000 accounts, which is too slow.

I guess the reason is the last line, but I didn't manage to refactor it well

```
LEFT JOIN NEXT_B_DAYS ON AS_AS_RECEPTION_CONF.CALENDAR_ID =
   NEXT_B_DAYS.CAL_ID AND LATEST_CB_DATES.BAL_DATE =
   NEXT_B_DAYS.BUSINESS_DATE
```

The exeuction plan of my sql can be found [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byqwnzarg)

How can I refactor this to make my view still work but much more performant?

Comment: @DarshakGajjar wow, that's the advice? Do you understand what nolock does? Jonas - Please provide the execution plan for the query, post it to http://www.pastetheplan.com and update your question with the link to that page.

Comment: @DarshakGajjar First never advice `Nolock` without pointing out the problems it may cause.

Comment: I added the execution plan to the question